# How to solve white stripes issue on printer

Tags: printing, printer, maintenance, lexmark-printer

I have an old [Lexmark x502n](http://www.lexmark.com/US/en/catalog/product.jsp?prodId=3952&catId=cat170005) Laser Multifunction color printer.

It works perfectly, except it stripes everything I print with white lines:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I searched on internet and it seems that whenever something like this happens it means that you have to clean toners (their contacts) and sometimes you have to clean rollers. I did search in the printer utilities software and unfortunately there is no option to do it automatically.

Is that right? If not, what should I do, and how should I do it?

Comment: Did you clean the toners and contacts (there is usually a setting to do so)?

Comment: @Dave Hi! I actually can't find a setting to do it, so I was thinking of manually cleaning toners and contacts, but I wanted someone to confirm that it's the right thing to do

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to state that, it's pretty important :)

Comment: @Dave I edited the question. Thanks for the reference, I'll follow the instructions. I also found [this](http://www.lexmark.com/publications/pdfs/2007/x500/v2031317_en.pdf), that at page 103 explains how to manually clean the printer, I'll try that too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should read 2-62 and 2-63 of the manual as these seem to be specific for your printer.

However, read [this page of the manual](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Lexmark/X502n/Manual/323624?page=95) and onwards as there is a lot of information which is similar to your issue!

Comment: I opened the printer and removed the photodeveloper cartridge, as described in the manual. It is full of stripes, in the exact same points where the printing has white stripes, so I really think that's the problem. Now, I think I will buy another printer, as just that cartridge costs around 300$... Thanks though!